# How can I trigger arrow-key according to the const 'value'?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, arrow-keys

Hi I know the title of my post is quite tricky, so let me talk about it in detail here. I'm working on html+js page that gets the orientation value from my smartphone. The two devices are connected through google firebase, and it gets the realtime orientation value when my smartphone is on that page. I'm having trouble with connecting this value with the function of triggering the arrow keys.

For example, if the beta value is more than 0, up-key is triggered, etc.

I'm trying to use this orientation value to trigger up, down, left, right keys to be pressed accordingly, but I couldn't find any clue for it. What I get from google or stackflow was usually about connecting functions with the keyboard-events, but what I'm trying to do is the opposite; triggering keyboard-events based on conditions of the orientation values.

I'd appreciate if anyone can give me some clues or quick examples, so that I can twick. Sorry that I couldn't link any jsfiddles or part of the code since it's already connected with my firebase!

p.s. the code part I'm showing below is the part I checked it's working! I checked the orientations values are valid.

```
const controlAlpha = document.querySelector("#alpha").innerText;
const controlBeta = document.querySelector("#beta").innerText;
const controlGamma = document.querySelector("#gamma").innerText;

betaControl = function(){
    if (textBeta<0){
        console.log("beta under 0");
    }

    else{
        console.log("beta over 0");
    }

}
betaControl();
```

Comment: First, what's textBeta?

Second, you can't trigger the keys, you can only trigger the events that are assoicated with keys. For example, if you have an event `doUp();` that is called when the up arrow on the keyboard is pressed, then call the function `doUp()` when you need it. Also, you can trigger the even associated via javascript (`keypress` for example)

Comment: Hi Damir! Sorry for the late comment. Thanks to your comment I managed to tweak the project a bit and solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad I could help you figure it out :)